# Embedding Content on a site with ‘X-Frame-Options’ to ‘SAMEORIGIN’

Tags: php, apache, same-origin-policy

I have a multimedia site contains thousands of videos. I had to prevent "clickjacking" due to some problems I occured.

The thing is when I include the following header to my httpd.config file, users cannot share my videos through social networks or applications.

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

I host the embed videos through `https://example.org/embed/VIDEO-ID`

Is it possible to disable `X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN` just for embed videos? If so, could you please explain it to me?

What I have tried so far;

- I tried to remove header in /embed/ with PHP
- I tried to unset the header in /embed/

On httpd I've done the following;

```
header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

On /embed/ page I am doing the following;

```
header_remove("X-Frame-Options");
header('X-Frame-Options: GOFORIT');
```

Comment: Show us how you are appending that header and how you tried removing it.

Comment: @apokryfos I have updated the content about how I append and remove, thanks :)

Comment: I doubt that you can remove a header you've set via httpd in PHP. It depends when it's set. If it's set after PHP is ran then it doesn't make a difference. I think you should consider adding headers in an .htaccess and making an exception if the link is embed.  Syntax should be similar to the httpd.